# https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("ARSARS")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Tags: yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I have been using the following URL for the past 3 years without issue. However, it has stopped returning results.

URL:
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("ARSARS")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Now returns the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2017-11-02T09:33:25Z" yahoo:lang="en-AU">
    <results/>
</query><!-- total: 9 -->
```

Notice how there are no results, it simply has the tag "results".
I have tried on this many different computers and browsers.  I have also tried changing the currency combinations, but no luck.

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've just formatted your post for better readability. Would you be able to change your title to better capture the essence of your problem, instead of what it currently is as it'll help your question get discovered and answered?

Comment: https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Known-issues-and-updates/Finance-download-error-999/m-p/387511#M13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has Yahoo suddenly today terminated its finance download API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064776/has-yahoo-suddenly-today-terminated-its-finance-download-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it looks like Yahoo has discontinued their Currency Converter API service.

I found a different site : https://currencylayer.com/

They let you request currency rates (1 USD = 168 other currencies). If you make less than 1000 requests per month, it is free (if you need more, they have different subscriptions : https://currencylayer.com/product).

You just need to sign up and receive your own Access Code. Once you have that, then you simply make the call http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=  and it will return JSON of the other currency rates.

They also have code examples in PHP, JavaScript, and Java at https://currencylayer.com/documentation

Found it very easy to get started using their API right away.

Comment: one additoin: If you want to convert from anything but USD you need to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the API is down.

I am similarly receiving `"results"=null`for the query:
`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+%2A+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in+%28%22GBPEUR%22%29&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys`

Setting `diagnostics=true` in the request yields:
`

```
[execution-start-time] => 7
[execution-stop-time] => 12
[execution-time] => 5
[http-status-code] => 999
[http-status-message] => Request denied
[content] => http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=snl1d1t1ab
```

`

If anyone knows more than me about what this might imply I'd be glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo is aware of this issue and their engineers are working on it:

ref: https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/http-download-finance-yahoo-com-d-quotes-csv-s-GOOG-amp-f/td-p/387096

Comment: Oops. The same link as above now shows Yahoo is discontinuing the service. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Very sadly and quite outrageously Yahoo decided to stop this service without any warning.

See admin message [here](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/http-download-finance-yahoo-com-d-quotes-csv-s-GOOG-amp-f/td-p/387096)
[image: Yahoo screenshot - Admin says no more finance API]

So many services depend on it, it's like Google saying they would suddenly stop their maps API... At this point I am blocking yahoo in our DNS so no one in our company will ever use Yahoo again since they are not a reliable entity.